# Templates tags in Play 2.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

Is there built in templates and tags in play 2.x,similar to what we had in play 1.x version ? Please share if there is any reference.
Trying to move from Play 1.x to 2.x. Has anybody tried it directly moving from 1.x to the latest of play?

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.x you can simply use view templates instead of tags from version 1.x. For instance, let's say that you want a reusable template which displays a header. You create a view file, e.g. **views/templates/appHeader.scala.html** with the following content:

```
@(header: String)

<div class="app-header">
  <h1>@header</h1>
</div>
```

Next, in a file where you want to use it you call it by putting this line of code:

```
@views.html.templates.appHeader("New app header")
```

You can read more about templates in Play 2 in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates).

There's no any official migration guide for 1.x to 2.x. However, you can find some blog posts about migration on the web.